# How to assign single pointer into double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I saw this example:

```
int main()
{
  char *ls[] = {"ls", NULL};
  char *grep[] = {"grep", "pipe", NULL};
  char *wc[] = {"wc", NULL};
  char **cmd[] = {ls, grep, wc, NULL};

  loop_pipe(cmd);
  return (0);
}
```

And loop_pipe() is a function to manipulate the arguments for multiple pipes. But the variables on this code which are inserted into cmd are already defined. 
On my personal code I'm trying to do the opposite, create the variable, insert the arguments into the variable and then add it to cmd. But what isn't happening is the 'adding' need. For instance, the code look like this:

```
*(cmd[pipe_count]) = arg;
```

I guess there is something wrong ('cause it's not working) but isn't using an index to set the location of insertion sufficient to allocate a pointer of array inside my double pointer? If not can someone help me clear how to assign like this?

Edit1:

My code simplified is like this:

```
char* arg[100];
char** cmd[100] = {};
int pipe_count = 0;
int index = 0;
arg[pipe_count] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    for (int k = 0; params_vector[k][0] != '\0'; k++) {             // percorrer todos os parametros. exemplo: ls | less | sort
        if (strcmp(params_vector[k], "|") != 0) {
            arg[index] = params_vector[k];
            index++;
        } else {
            arg[index] = '\0';
            *(cmd) = arg;
            pipe_count++;
            arg[pipe_count] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM);
            index = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "_Isn't using an index to set the location of insertion sufficient to allocate a pointer of array inside my double pointer?_" - Not at all. You cannot change the size of a statically allocated array. You should allocate the array dynamically with malloc() and then use realloc() to expand it.

Comment: @Dyz since my arg is allocated with malloc at the beggining of the program (code: arg[pipe_count] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); ), isn't it allocated enough for the insertion?

Comment: No. You have to allocate `char **cmd` dynamically, too, because you expect its size to change. Alternatively, you can reserve some extra space for further expansion at the time of declaration: `char **cmd[MAX_SIZE] = {ls, grep, wc, NULL};` (Note the `MAX_SIZE`!)

Comment: My cmd is declared as char** cmd[100] = {}; when initialized, so should I malloc it too?

Comment: No, unless you plan to store more than 100 elements. Please provide a consistent code example. What you show us in the post now apparently is not what you really use.

Comment: char **cmd is a *** pointer. You just became a three star programmer!!!!!!! But it is not good - http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer    My advice - reconsider your idea again,

Comment: @DyZ I uploaded part of the code

Comment: @E.Akio read my comment. Reconsider your idea.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I liked your suggestion, I personally don't know a lot about using lots of pointers, but... thanks for the link

Comment: @E.Akio it is a wrong idea. Extremely error prone, unmaintainable (I bet you will not remember those *** pointers were for after couple of days or even hours.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 if it's already messing up, i can't imagine if i'll have to use it for others cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of `char **cmd[]` as an array which contains `char **` elements. So you can assign `char **` elements to it.

```
cmd[i] = arg;
```

It's as simple as that. It's not much different from an array of integers.

```
// "foo" is a `const char[]`. So an array of them is a `const char *[]`
const char *ls[] = {"ls", NULL};
const char *grep[] = {"grep", "pipe", NULL};
const char *wc[] = {"wc", NULL};

// To store an array of `const char *[]` we need a `const char **[]`.
const char **cmd[10] = {NULL};

cmd[0] = ls;
cmd[1] = grep;
cmd[2] = wc;
```

In more detail...

For simplicity, the rest of this example will treat `char *[]` and `char **` the same. There's some subtle differences, but for our purposes they don't matter. We'll treat `ls`, `grep`, and `wc` as `char **` pointers and `cmd` as `char ***`.

`char **cmd[10]` allocates space for 10 `char **` pointers on the [stack](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html). `char **` are the same size as any other pointers. We'll assume 64 bit integers or 8 bytes. 10 of them means it allocates 80 bytes. `cmd` itself is a `char ***` pointer. That only has meaning to the compiler for type checking purposes. Ultimately all `cmd` contains is a 64 bit integer representing a location in memory.

Same with `ls`, `grep`, and `wc`. They are of type `char **` which is just a 64 bit integer representing a location in memory.

`cmd[0] = ls` says to start at the address of `cmd`, advance by the size of 0 `char **` pointers (so 0), and then assign the `char **` pointer contained in the `ls` to that location. So if `cmd` is at memory location 100, this writes to 100 through 107.

`cmd[1] = grep` says to start at the address of `cmd`, 100. Advance by the size of 1 `char **` pointers, 8. Then assign the `char **` pointer contained in `grep` to that location. So 100 + 8 is 108. Then write 8 bytes to 108 through 115.

And `cmd[2] = grep` writes the 64 bit number in `grep` to memory location 100 + (2 * 8) or 116 through 123.

And so on. It works this way for any array of pointers. Or pointers to pointers. It's just a fancy array of integers.